# Animating svg line along with table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a horizontal event timeline where I can show some data on hovering. This is what I have done so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="timeline">
    <table class="table table-responsive" style="border-color: transparent;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="grow">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <br>2007</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <br>2009</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                <br>2013</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
                <br>Present</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <svg width="100%">
      <line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
timeline {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.grow {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lmgyzr50/3/

I am trying to achieve something like the timeline below in this demo page :

It is above the Our Experts tab in the home page itself.

[Demo Page](http://logicsforest.com/multi-page-demo-3/index.html)

Please tell me how I can achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure css, html, and javascript, go ahead and give it a go, it works exactly like the example.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7aew84c/8/

```js
$("[link-assoc]").hide();
$("[link]").hover(function () {
 $("[link-assoc="+$(this).attr("link")+"]")
   .stop(true,true)
   .slideToggle()
      .siblings()
    .stop(true,true)
      .slideUp();
});
```

```css
timeline {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.container {
  height:100px;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  min-height:5px;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  background:rgb(255,0,0);
}

.container {
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}

.grow {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="timeline">
    <table class="table table-responsive" style="border-color: transparent;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="grow" link="1">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <br>2007</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow" link="2">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <br>2009</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow" link="3">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                <br>2013</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="grow" link="4">
              <p style="font-size: 1.25em"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
                <br>Present</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <div id="content">
      <div link-assoc="1">
        test1
      </div>
      <div link-assoc="2">
        test2
      </div>
      <div link-assoc="3">
        test3
      </div>
      <div link-assoc="4">
        test4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/54Lxweqj/ .  If you could mark as solution and up vote, it'd help a lot.

Comment: This isn't what I wanted. I wanted that svg line to raise on hovering over the table cell like in the example shown in the demo. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: @v1shnu  I spent some time working on it: https://jsfiddle.net/b7aew84c/8/ . If you could upvote and mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To animate the line shape like that in SVG, you need to morph the shape of a path.

Here's an example of how to do that using SVG's built-in SMIL animation elements.

```html
<svg id="line1" width="100%" viewBox="0 -3 120 36">
  <path d="M0,30 c20,0,40,0,60,0 c20,0,40,0,60,0"
        style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5">
    <animate attributeName="d"
             to="M0,30 c20,0,40,-30,60,-30 c20,0,40,30,60,30"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="line1.mouseenter"
             fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="d"
             to="M0,30 c20,0,40,0,60,0 c20,0,40,0,60,0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="line1.mouseleave"
             fill="freeze"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

And here is an your fiddle updated with one of these SVGs for each of your columns. https://jsfiddle.net/Lmgyzr50/4/

This is the "easy" way to do it.  There are other ways you could do it that don't involve having multiple copies of (almost) the same SVG. But you would need to use Javascript for those.

Comment: Nice solution. Can you provide an example or tutorial where it shows shows to modify the path of the line based on the cursor position on that line?

Comment: I actually thought of getting the clientX value and modifying the line properties based on that using jquery. But I could not seem to find a tutorial or example for that.

Comment: So you don't want it column based, like that demo page? You want it to raise anywhere along the line, wherever the pointer is?

Comment: I planned to modify the raise so that it is in accordance with the table cells. In that way, at that region, both my line and the table cell will grow.

Comment: Also I'm looking at animate.css library and seeing if that can be used along with this line.

Comment: If that it the case, why is the method in my modified fiddle not acceptable to you?

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason, the fiddle does not work when viewed on phone. Anyway I will check it once I am at my PC. Thanks for your solution. I will get back to you if I need any clarifications regarding your solution.